# Paypal Express Checkout Updating Shipping

Tags: php, paypal

I am having getting PayPal to update shipping options based on country when a customer selects their shipping address.

I am attempting to use the [Paypal Instant Update API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/) and have followed the instructions but to no avail.

I am currently just using the Paypal Sandbox; but it doesn't seem to behave.

I am able to generate what I believe is the correct response and send it, however Paypal just uses the defaults set with the initial request. Logs show the response being sent, I've even put the response in to a database so I can see what it was (and it is as expected).

I've tried may things http, https, disable gzip, urlencode, file with static content, and nothing seems to be working. Here is what my response currently looks like:

```
METHOD=CallbackResponse&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=2nd+Class&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=2nd+Class&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=1.50&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=1st+Class&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=1st+Class&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=2.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=Special+Delivery&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=Special+Delivery&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=6.00&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, and Paypal don't seem to offer any way to debug callbacks. Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you try and remove L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABELN from the response? Or rename it to L_SHIPINGPOPTIONLABELN? (yes, I'm serious, back when I integrated this, we had a typo in that variable)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Initially I didn't have this in, but added it. Just tried removing it, and also renaming it as suggested, but it is still not working.